# Why doesn't this sentence include "who" or "that"? "...present to some people {who} we hope..."

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, syntax, optional-that

> I'm going to present to some people we hope will become investors.

I think the sentence should be changed into one below.

> I'm going to present to some people [who] we hope will become investors.

I don't know why the sentence is missing 'who' or 'that'

Comment: It's OK as it is. You can have either a _wh_ relative, or a non-_wh_ relative (_that_ or bare).